# wordpress - user registration ( signup registration )

Tags: user-registration

I am working on a blogging website ..!

I need to create Signup Registration and allow multiple users to blog on our website.

i.e ) Website will blogged by myself and also allows any registered users to blog on our website. In addition we allow any anonymous comments to be posted on the blogs.

A registered user can tag / follow their favorite blogs.

How to create a Signup Registration on Wordpress Blogging Website and allow any registered users to blog on our website ?

Comment: User Registration is a built in feature of WordPress - you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned wordpress.com, I assume you're thinking of a blogging network.

You can do that using WordPress Multisite. Here's how to enable it:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Scribu, you are right. I am expecting blogging network.

Comment: I am just expecting something like huffingtonpost .. ! But on huffingtonpost, it shows powered by MovableType. Goal is to allow registered users to add their blogs.

Comment: Yes, on MultiSite you have a specific front-end template for user registration.

Comment: Techcrunch.com is on Wordpress VIP version ..! I dont see Signup Registration Page..! Anyways, all i want to know is How to allow Signup feature on blogging Website.?

Comment: This is the signup page: http://en.wordpress.com/signup/ which can of course be customized. Please don't ask any more questions before you set up your network, as it wastes everyone's time.

Comment: To reiterate: you won't see the signup page unless you activate MultiSite.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and activate the Login with Ajax widget on your sidebar to give users easy access to the registration form.

Comment: For wordpress signup - is there any third party softwware or plugins available ? or, i need to design the user registration form by myself ?

Comment: Can anyone could share links or samples of allowing User registration on wordpress ..!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few plugins that give you registration and login that are not the wp-admin route.  One is WP-Members.  A lot are described as members only section plugins but they give you the added benefit of using different registration and login forms than what is built into WP.  Still uses the users table though so it fits into the rest of WP user management and works with other user management plugins.

Answer (score 0):

@Chok

Gravity Forms is one of my favorite WordPress plugins and it has a great user registration option that will allow you to register users as well as create new sites on a multi-site blog when they register.  Goodluck.

[Check out Gravity Forms here.](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/)